# Jest - не получается замокать функцию модуля для каждого теста отдельно

Tags: javascript, node.js, юнит-тесты, jest

Есть такой код NodeJS AWS лямбда функции, которую я бы хотел покрыть юнит-тестами на Jest:

**index.js**

```
const { getConfig } = require('./modules/config/configManager');
const BridgeDataProvider = require('./modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
const ClientProcessor = require('./modules/domain/clientProcessor');
const configPromise = getConfig();

exports.handler = async () => {

    const config = await configPromise;
    if (!config.enabled) {
        return;
    }

    const bridgeDataProvider = new BridgeDataProvider(config.bridgeDynamoDbConfig);
    const clientProcessor = new ClientProcessor(config);

    const clients = await bridgeDataProvider.getActiveClients();

    for (const client of clients) {
        await clientProcessor.process(client);
    }
};
```

И я хочу иметь возможность замокать асинхронную функцию `getConfig` отдельно для каждого теста, но, к сожалению, приведенный ниже код не дает ожидаемого результата. `await getConfig()` в `index.js` всегда возвращает `undefined`:

**index.test.js**

```
const { getConfig } = require('../modules/config/configManager');
const { handler } = require('../index');
const BridgeDataProvider = require('../modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
const ClientProcessor = require('../modules/domain/clientProcessor');

jest.mock('../modules/config/configManager', () => ({
    getConfig: jest.fn(),
}));
jest.mock('../modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
jest.mock('../modules/domain/clientProcessor');

const defaultMocks = {
    BridgeDataProvider: {
        getActiveClients: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            /** @type {Client[]} */
            const clients = [
                {
                    id: '1234abc',
                    clientcode: 'Amazon',
                },
                {
                    id: '5678def',
                    clientcode: 'Facebook',
                },
            ];

            return Promise.resolve(clients);
        }),
    },
};

/**
 * @typedef {import('../modules/config/config.types').AppConfig} AppConfig
 * @typedef {import('../modules/storage/bridge/models.types').Client} Client
 */

describe('handler', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules()
            .clearAllMocks();
        
        setupDefaultMocks();
    });

    it('does not handle clients if function is not enabled', async () => {
        getConfig.mockResolvedValue({enabled: false, bridgeDynamoDbConfig: {}}); // this is not working, await getConfig() returns undefined in index.js

        await handler();

        const processMethod = ClientProcessor.mock.instances[0].process;
        expect(processMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    });
});

function setupDefaultMocks() {
    getConfig.mockResolvedValue({enabled: true, bridgeDynamoDbConfig: {}}); // this is not working, await getConfig() returns undefined in index.js

    BridgeDataProvider.mockImplementation(() => defaultMocks.BridgeDataProvider);
}
```

Test output:

```
 FAIL  test/index.test.js
  ● handler › does not handle clients if function is not enabled

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enabled')

      10 |
      11 |     const config = await configPromise;
    > 12 |     if (!config.enabled) {
         |                 ^
      13 |         return;
      14 |     }
      15 |

      at enabled (index.js:12:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/index.test.js:48:9)
```

Если же я замокаю `getConfig` через вызов `jest.mock('../modules/config/configManager', ...)`, возвращаемое значение замокается. Но мне нужно, чтобы я мог переопределить это замоканное значение в любом тесте.

**Вопрос:** Почему мок не применяется, и как тогда правильно его применить для каждого теста отдельно?

Comment: сейчас ошибка потому что мок функция ничего не возвращает.
чтобы работало - надо чтобы она возвращала - Promise.resolve({enabled: true});

Comment: Залейте куда-то вариант где мок работает

Comment: @Jackson `.mockResolvedValue(val)` - как раз и должен задавать мок, который возвращает `Promise.resolve(val)`. Проблема решена, меня навели на верную мысль на английском SO, позже тут дам ответ